# RecycleView with multiple types of child views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecycleView` and a `RecycleViewAdapter`, everything works fine with a single type of Row, then i have added a new Row (so now i have 2 kind of row) and the list starts behaving in a strange way.

as soon as the list is displayed the rows are correct, then i start adding elements to the list and i expect the first kind of row but the app displays the second type of row, sometimes it works, other times i expect the second kind and the app sows me the first kind.

Scrolling the list sometimes will change the type of row randomly.

looking at the log and using the debugger everything looks fine.

Any suggestion?

this is a part of the code:

complete code:

```
 public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview.StickyRecyclerHeadersAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private List<Message> messages;
    private boolean isMine;

    private int sent_imageRowResId = R.layout.row_messages_image_sent;
    private int sent_videoRowResId = R.layout.row_messages_video_sent;
    private int sent_audioRowResId = R.layout.row_messages_audio_sent;
    private int sent_textRowResId = R.layout.row_messages_text_sent;

    private int recv_imageRowResId = R.layout.row_messages_image_recv;
    private int recv_videoRowResId = R.layout.row_messages_video_recv;
    private int recv_audioRowResId = R.layout.row_messages_audio_recv;
    private int recv_textRowResId = R.layout.row_messages_text_recv;

    private static final int TEXT = 1;
    private static final int VIDEO = 2;
    private static final int IMAGE = 3;
    private static final int AUDIO = 4;


    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messages, Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.context = context;
        this.messages = messages;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {   
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        String senderAccountIdentifier = message.getSenderAccountIdentifier();

        isMine = senderAccountIdentifier.equals(userAccountIdentifier);

        int viewType = TEXT;

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) viewType = TEXT;
        else if (message instanceof VideoMessage) viewType = VIDEO;
        else if (message instanceof ImageMessage)viewType = IMAGE;
        else if (message instanceof AudioMessage) viewType = AUDIO;

      if (viewType == IMAGE) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(isMine ? sent_imageRowResId : recv_imageRowResId, parent, false);
            ViewHolderImage viewHolder = new ViewHolderImage(view);
            return viewHolder;
        } else if (viewType == VIDEO) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(isMine ? sent_videoRowResId : recv_videoRowResId, parent, false);
            ViewHolderVideo viewHolder = new ViewHolderVideo(view);
            return viewHolder;
        } else if (viewType == AUDIO) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(isMine ? sent_audioRowResId : recv_audioRowResId, parent, false);
            ViewHolderAudio viewHolder = new ViewHolderAudio(view);
            return viewHolder;
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(isMine ? sent_textRowResId : recv_textRowResId, parent, false);
            ViewHolderText viewHolder = new ViewHolderText(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {    
        if (holder instanceof BaseViewHolder) {

            final Message message = messages.get(position);

            final BaseViewHolder bvh = (BaseViewHolder) holder;
            bvh.dateTextView.setText(getDateString(position));
            bvh.senderTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            bvh.rowMessage.setActivated(selectedItems.get(position, false));

            if (bvh instanceof ViewHolderText) {
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    ViewHolderText viewHolderText = (ViewHolderText) bvh;
                    viewHolderText.init(textMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }
```

**EDIT**

Update with the almost the complete code

the difference with this 2 rows (i'm only using the text one) is only the color of the text and the layout gravity

**EDIT - SOLVED**

changing the return in `getItemViewType()` has solved the issue, i have replaced `return viewType` with `return position`, and i have moved some logic inside onCreateViewHolder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

follow this approach

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch(getItemViewType(position)){
        case 1: // put your values in the view
        case 2: // put your values in the view
    }


    class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // for your different positions, return different numbers say 1, 2 these numbers will signify your view types 
        return position viewType;
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount(){
         return 2;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 1: // handle your viewholder 1
             case 2: //handle your viewholder 2
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like my code, and with this code i have the issue

Comment: @frenk91 I can't see the "getViewTypeCount()" or "getItemViewType" in your code - these are what dictates multiple views, the different view types.

Comment: the content of my row is perfectly fine, the problems is the layout that iam usint to inflate. as soon as the list is displayed the rows are correct and the layout of them is fine, but if a scroll the list, or i add some element the layout get messy